# Find optimal vector that minimizes function

Tags: python, vector, scipy, quadratic-programming, quadprog

I am trying to find a vector that minimizes the residual sum of squares when multiplying a matrix.

I know of scipy's optimize package (which has a minimize function). However, there is an extra constraint for my code. The sum of all entries of w (see function below) must equal 1, and no entry of w can be less than 0. **Is there a package that does this for me?** If not, how can I do this?

Trying to minimize w:

```
def w_rss(w,x0,x1):
    predictions = np.dot(x0,w)
    errors = x1 - predictions
    rss = np.dot(errors.transpose(),errors).item(0)

    return rss

X0 = np.array([[3,4,5,3],
               [1,2,2,4],
               [6,5,3,7],
               [1,0,5,2]])  

X1 = np.array([[4],
               [2],
               [4],
               [2]]) 

W = np.array([[.0],
              [.5],
              [.5],
              [.0]])

print w_rss(W,X0,X1)
```

So far this is my best attempt at looping through possible values of w, but it's not working properly.

```
def get_w(x0,x1):

J = x0.shape[1]
W0 = np.matrix([[1.0/J]*J]).transpose()
rss0 = w_rss(W0,x0,x1)
loop = range(J)
for i in loop:
    W1 = W0
    rss1 = rss0
    while rss0 == rss1:
        den = len(loop)-1
        W1[i][0] += 0.01
        for j in loop:
            if i == j:
                continue
            W1[j][0] -= 0.01/den
            if W1[j][0] <= 0:
                loop.remove(j)
        rss1 = w_rss(W1,x0,x1)
        if rss1 < rss0:
            #print W1
            W0 = W1
            rss0 = rss1
        print '--'
        print rss0
        print W0

return W0,rss0
```

Comment: You can use any QP (quadratic programming) solver for this.

Comment: I tried this in scipy.optimize: cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  1 - sum(x)}) {{NEW LINE}} bnds = tuple((0,1) for x in W) {{NEW LINE}} minimize(w_rss, W1, args=(V,X0,X1), method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons). Solution was incorrect.

Comment: This is a general purpose NLP solver. It should work with a properly setup problem but I would recommend to use a real QP solver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SLSQP code in scipy can do this.  You can use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) with `method='SLSQP`, or you can use the function [`fmin_slsqp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html) directly.  In the following, I use `fmin_slsqp`.

The scipy solvers generally pass a *one-dimensional* array to the objective function, so to be consistent, I'll change `W` and `X1` to be 1-d arrays, and I'll write the objective function (now called `w_rss1`) to expect a 1-d argument `w`.

The condition that all the elements in `w` must be between 0 and 1 is specified using the `bounds` argument, and the condition that the sum must be 1 is specified using the `f_eqcons` argument.  The constraint function returns `np.sum(w) - 1`, so it is 0 when the sum of the elements is 1.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin_slsqp


def w_rss1(w, x0, x1):
    predictions = np.dot(x0, w)
    errors = x1 - predictions
    rss = (errors**2).sum()
    return rss


def sum1constraint(w, x0, x1):
    return np.sum(w) - 1


X0 = np.array([[3,4,5,3],
               [1,2,2,4],
               [6,5,3,7],
               [1,0,5,2]])  

X1 = np.array([4, 2, 4, 2]) 

W = np.array([.0, .5, .5, .0])

result = fmin_slsqp(w_rss1, W, f_eqcons=sum1constraint, bounds=[(0.0, 1.0)]*len(W),
                    args=(X0, X1), disp=False, full_output=True)
Wopt, fW, its, imode, smode = result

if imode != 0:
    print("Optimization failed: " + smode)
else:
    print(Wopt)
```

When I run this, the output is

```
[ 0.05172414  0.55172414  0.39655172  0.        ]
```